# What is the appropriate webpack loader to use static keywords?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, webpack-loader, react-styleguidist

I have the following error when I try to start my react-styleguidist documentation:

```
./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/touchables/TouchableHighlight.js 10:22
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| export default class TouchableHighlight extends Component {
>   static defaultProps = {
|     ...GenericTouchable.defaultProps,
|     activeOpacity: 0.85,
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/touchables/index.js 6:0-69 6:0-69
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js
```

My `webpack.config.js` look like this:

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');
module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);
  return config;
};
```

My `babel.config.js` look like this:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    env: {
      development: {
        plugins: [
          '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source',
        ],
      },
    },
  };
};
```

### Reproduction:

```
git clone https://github.com/kopax/expo-bug-reports.git
cd expo-bug-reports
git checkout react-styleguidist
npm i
npm run styleguide
```

What is the appropriate Webpack loader to use the `static` keyword?

Comment: Please show your `webpack.config.js` file.

Comment: use babel-loader with this babel plugin, https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Comment: I just updated my question with configuration and reproduction on GitHub. Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use webpack for build your project, then you need to add the babel-loader to webpack.

```
module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(j|t)sx?$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            use: [{
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
                    env: {
                      development: {
                        plugins: [
                          '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source',
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                }
            }]
        },
}
```

Comment: This is how I have configured [this rule](https://github.com/rollup-umd/documentation/blob/master/src/createConfig.js#L291). According to babel-loader, if nothing is specified, it should take from `babel.config.js`, why isn't it doing it automatically ?

Comment: I have tried to add the `options` by editing the source I've linked previously in [`node_modules/@rollup-umd/documentation/lib/createConfig`](https://github.com/rollup-umd/documentation/blob/master/src/createConfig.js#L291) but I have the exact **same error**.